# Ruby array += vs push

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays and want to append elements to the sub-arrays. += does what I want, but I'd like to understand why push does not.

Behavior I expect (and works with +=):

```
b = Array.new(3,[])
b[0] += ["apple"]
b[1] += ["orange"]
b[2] += ["frog"]
```

b => [["apple"], ["orange"], ["frog"]]

With push I get the pushed element appended to EACH sub-array (why?):

```
a = Array.new(3,[])
a[0].push("apple")
a[1].push("orange")
a[2].push("frog")
```

a => [["apple", "orange", "frog"], ["apple", "orange", "frog"], ["apple", "orange", "frog"]]

Any help on this much appreciated.

Comment: There's no wrong questions, but there ARE wrong answers. This is my first question. I've been coding Ruby for 2 days (coding for 40 years), created classes to handle everything to do with playing decks for any game (self training). This is the first issue I could not figure out via documentation (Yup I missed something in documentation--I'm sure that never happens to you). I did search for "ruby += push" and a couple other tries and found nothing here. Eiko's generous spirit is a good guide, @Jorg. I'm sure you're a good "recreational programmer", you don't have to prove it by trolling noobs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here is `b = Array.new(3, [])` uses the same object as the base value for all the array cells:

```
b = Array.new(3, [])
b[0].object_id #=> 28424380
b[1].object_id #=> 28424380
b[2].object_id #=> 28424380
```

So when you use `b[0].push`, it adds the item to "each" sub-array because they are all, in fact, the same array.

So why does b[0] += ["value"] work? Well, looking at the ruby docs:

> ## ary + other_ary → new_ary
>
> Concatenation — Returns a new array built by concatenating the two arrays together to produce a third array.

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ] + [ 4, 5 ]    #=> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
c = a + [ "d", "e", "f" ]
c                         #=> [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" ]
a                         #=> [ "a", "b", "c" ]
```

> Note that

```
x += y
```

> is the same as

```
x = x + y
```

> This means that it produces a new array. As a consequence, repeated use of += on arrays can be quite inefficient.

So when you use `+=`, it replaces the array entirely, meaning the array in `b[0]` is no longer the same as `b[1]` or `b[2]`.

As you can see:

```
b = Array.new(3, [])
b[0].push("test") 
b #=> [["test"], ["test"], ["test"]]
b[0].object_id #=> 28424380
b[1].object_id #=> 28424380
b[2].object_id #=> 28424380
b[0] += ["foo"]
b #=> [["test", "foo"], ["test"], ["test"]]
b[0].object_id #=> 38275912
b[1].object_id #=> 28424380
b[2].object_id #=> 28424380
```

---

If you're wondering how to ensure each array is unique when initializing an array of arrays, you can do so like this:

```
b = Array.new(3) { [] }
```

This different syntax lets you pass a block of code which gets run for each cell to calculate its original value. Since the block is run for each cell, a separate array is created each time.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is my first question here and I don't know how to set your answer as the "right" one. Thanks for the efficiency comment also. I'll watch out for that. BTW solved by: 'b=Array.new(3)'   '3.times  {|i| b[i] = []}' (if there is a better way to "break the object link" please let me). --Just an old c/c++/c# programer teaching himself ruby :)

Comment: @DavidBunnell I'm glad to help! If you look at the top-left corner of this answer, you should see a check-mark (next to the score and up/down arrows for voting). If you click that check-mark, it'll turn green, letting everyone know this answer worked for you. Welcome to stackoverflow and happy coding ^_^

Comment: @DavidBunnell also, I've updated my answer with a more eloquent way to initialize the array. The code you mentioned in your comment is similar though!

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the second code section, you're selecting the sub-array and pushing to it, if you want an array of array's you need to push the array to the main array.

```
a = Array.new(3,[])
a.push(["apple"])
a.push(["orange"])
a.push(["frog"])
```

to get the same result as the first one.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, because you initialize the array with blank array's as elements, you will have three empty elements in front of the pushed elements,

Comment: This isn't right and ignores the source of the problem: The `[]` argument to `Array.new` which creates a *shared* array for all entries.